# Send keys from Android to PC by screen location

Tags: android, ios

I am displaying a flight simulator instrument panel on my Samsumg Note 8 and would like to send keystrokes to the PC application by touching certain parts of the screen. For example I might touch the area where a + button is displayed to adjust an instrument. It is a custom layout and no mouse clicks are relevant so I really need to send keystrokes. Can this be done 'over the top' of the displayed instrument panel, i.e. silently detect the touch points and send keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

return false;
}
```

Just overide this method in your custom view.